# rails routes for static binary file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I placed some binary file under `Public' folder, and while trying to access it through http server,an error occurs:

> It is possible that you didn't upload your application files correctly. Please check whether all your application files are uploaded.
>   A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.

I need place some binary files(dmg,exe,etc) on my rails app and allow others to download it.

Comment: so you want people to access say http://yoursite.com/download/path_to_file ?

or do you plan to link to it? What was the route you made and what was the url you were going to? please provide more details

Comment: I need access `host.com/file_name`, and the file was placed in the `public` folder. no special routes for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a web host issue to me... Apache or Nginx would normally handle static files without Rails getting called.  Unless you are using ActionDispatch::Static or are in development mode?

Comment: I recreated an Rails site... and it works without any configures. might be someting wrong to my nginx service.